# Timeout in a delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have some code that potentially can run for a longer period of time. However if it does I want to kill it, here is what I'm doing at the moment :

```
def perform
    Timeout.timeout(ENV['JOB_TIMEOUT'].to_i, Exceptions::WorkerTimeout) { do_perform }
  end
```

private
  def do_perform
    ...some code...
  end

Where `JOB_TIMEOUT` is an environment variable with value such as `10.seconds`. I've got reports that this still doesn't prevent my job from running longer that it should.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe delayed_job does some exception handling voodoo with multiple retries etc, not to mention that I *think* `do_perform` will return immediately and the job will continue as usual in another thread.  I would imagine a better approach is doing flow control inside the worker

```
def perform
  # A nil timeout will continue with no timeout, protect against unset ENV
  timeout = (ENV['JOB_TIMEOUT'] || 10).to_i

  do_stuff

  begin
  Timeout.timeout(timeout) { do_long_running_stuff }
  rescue Timeout::Error
    clean_up_after_self
    notify_business_logic_of_failure
  end
end
```

This will work.  Added benefits are not coupling delayed_job so tightly with your business logic - this code can be ported to any other job queueing system unmodified.